# Вывод данных из таблицы sql

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Имеется таблица sql и код для вывода **ВСЕХ** строк из базы:

```
 $db_host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db_name = '111';
    $db_username = '111';
    $db_password = '111';
    $db_table_to_show = 'zav';

    $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
  or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

    mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
  or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());
    $qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . $db_table_to_show)
  or die(mysql_error());

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $data['name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['adress'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>'; }
```

Этим самым выводятся все строки со значениями `bar` и `cafe`.
Как мне сделать вывод строк именно со значением `cafe`?

Заранее спасибо. )

Comment: @Евгений Заречнев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Этим самым выводятся все строки таблицы zav.

Судя по вопросу ответ слишком банален:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $data['adress'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>'; }
```

Либо такой:

```
  $qr_result = mysql_query("select adress from " . $db_table_to_show)

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['adress'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>'; }
```

Ну и совет, почитайте документацию, разберите банальные примеры, если не получается понимать задачи из разряда Hello World, то лучше не браться за это.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from `таблица` where `колонка` = `значение`
```

Comment: Спасибо, а не могли бы вы именно в моем примере описать, как это сделать, и еще, я дописал строки, посмотрите их, пожалуйста в коде, это то, что должно выводиться, но только те, которые со значением "bar".

Спасибо.

Comment: @Евгений Заречнев, а что такое bar и cafe? Не увидел их в вашем коде. Возможно, это данные в БД, но тогда вопрос - в какой колонке они хранятся? Name или adress? @Bastian дал исчерпывающий ответ, а вы просите еще и "пережевать его за вас и в рот положить". Включайте мозг!